# Split a string based on delimiters and insert splits into table as rows

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a string is as follows:

```
L1N:0V L2N:0V L3N:0V L12:0V L23:0V L31:0V IL1:0A IL2:0A IL3:0A RPM:0 FREQ:0.00Hz P:0.00psi T:64'C Fuel:43% kVA:0 BVolt:27.00V Hrs:2272
```

I am interested in the splits that are bold in the following string

> L1N:**0**V L2N:**0**V L3N:**0**V L12:**0**V L23:**0**V L31:**0**V IL1:**0**A IL2:**0**A IL3:**0**A RPM:0 FREQ:**0.00**Hz P:**0.00**psi T:**64**'C Fuel:**43**% kVA:**0** BVolt:**27.00**V Hrs:**2272**

And I want to create multiple rows for each of these splits as shown below.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>64</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>43</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>27</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>2272</td>
    </tr>


  </table>
```

Comment: Well, start showing us what have you tried and tell us what is not working.

Comment: That's not splitting, that's parsing. you can use a regular expression to parse every number that is after a colon in your string, and then create a data table from it and send that data table to sql server. **However**, this is way beyond the scope of stackoverflow. This Q & A website is for **specific** questions, meaning one thing you can't handle in your code. it's not a "Please write my code for me" kind of website.

Comment: Thank you very much Zohar. I got it by using
string[] parts = string.Split(' ',':');
I got 34 splits and out of those 34, I get every second split and parse that split into integer to get the desired result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While agreeing with the comments above, try this for starters:

```
string[] substring = myString.Split(':');
foreach (string str in substrings){
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str){
          var val = double.tryParse(str);
              }
          }
```

And then use those values for your html (in javascript it would be something like

`var table = document.getElementById('myTable'); 
var row = table.insertRow(0); 
cell1 = row.insertCell(0); 
cell1.innerHTML = val;`